# Proving that the connect sum of 3 copies of $\mathbb{C}P^2$ does not have a complex structure

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, complex-geometry

Pardon my total lack of knowledge in complex geometry.  How would one go about proving that the connect sum of 3 copies of $\mathbb{C}P^2$ does not admit a complex structure?  Note that this manifold does admit an almost complex structure.